# Replace entire string anywhere in dataframe based on partial match with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm struggling to find the right dplyr code to use `grepl` or an equivalent to replace values throughout an entire data frame.

i.e.: any  cell that contains 'mazda'  in it, should have it's entire content replaced with the new string 'A car'

after lots of searching online, the closest I came was:

The emphasis being on applying it to ALL columns.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars$carnames <- rownames(mtcars)  # dummy data to test on
```

This line does the trick for entire sting being an exact match:

```
mtcars %>% replace(., (.)=='Mazda RX4', "A car")
```

but my grepl attempt replaces the entire column with "A car" for some reason.

```
mtcars %>% replace(., grepl('Mazda', (.)), "A car")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate_if(grepl('Mazda',.), ~replace(., grepl('Mazda', .), "A car"))
```

To understand why you first `replace` failed see the difference between `'Mazda RX4'==mtcars` and `grepl('Mazda', mtcars)`, since you used `grepl`, `replace` uses

> replace replaces the values in x with indices given in list by those given in values. **If necessary, the values in values are recycled.**

Now we can use your first method if we make sure to get a suitable output using `sapply` for example

```
mtcars %>% replace(., sapply(mtcars, function(.) grepl('Mazda',.)), "A car")
```

Update:

TO replace multiple patterns we can use `stringr::str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate_if(str_detect(., 'Mazda|Merc'), 
                    ~str_replace_all(., c("Mazda.*" = "A car", "Merc.*" = "B car")))
```

Comment: Ah, was missing the mutate_all wrapper. Would you know if there is also a way to replace a second string with another replacement (i.e `grepl('Merc', .), "B car")`) in the same mutate_all, or do I have to add another wrapper for that?

Comment: Sorry, my first answer wasn't complete, please see my update. for your 2nd question, we can do `mtcars %>% mutate_all(~case_when(grepl('Mazda', .)~'A car', grepl('Merc', .)~'B car', TRUE ~ as.character(.)))`, but one min let me check if we can do multiple `replace`.

Comment: `str_replace_all` much better than `case_when` as it will not change numeric columns into character columns same for `mutate_all` and `mutate_if`

Comment: The "updated" with additional multiple combinations is the real winner of this answer.