# Replace multiple values in data table column after multiple pattern match

Tags: r, string, design-patterns, replace, data.table

Here is a snippet that could help a few 'R beginners' like me:
I was referring to this thread for a need on my *melted* data table:

[Replace entire string anywhere in dataframe based on partial match with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325081/replace-entire-string-anywhere-in-dataframe-based-on-partial-match-with-dplyr)

I was looking for an easy way of replacing an entire string in one of the columns in data table with a partial match string. I could not find a straight fit on the forum, hence this post.

```
dt<-data.table(x=c("A_1", "BB_2", "CC_3"),y=c("K_1", "LL_2", "MM_3"),z=c("P_1","QQ_2","RR_3")
> dt
      x    y    z
1:  A_1  K_1  P_1
2: BB_2 LL_2 QQ_2
3: CC_3 MM_3 RR_3
```

replace multiple values in col `y` with multiple patterns to match:

```
dt[,2]<-str_replace_all(as.matrix(dt[,2]),c("K_.*" = "FORMULA","LL_.*" = "RACE","MM_.*" = "CAR"))
```

using `as.matrix()` on column excludes the warning on input to the `str_replace_all()` function.
The result is:

```
> dt[,2]<-str_replace_all(as.matrix(dt[,2]),c("K_.*" = "FORMULA","LL_.*" = "RACE","MM_.*" = "CAR"))
> dt
      x       y    z
1:  A_1 FORMULA  P_1
2: BB_2    RACE QQ_2
3: CC_3     CAR RR_3
>
```

very un-elegant, but worked for me, when the column data is large, this seemed to be a quick solution.

Requires `library(stringr)`.
Any suggestions to improve are appreciated.

*Editing this post as I tried something as below:*

```
dt<-data.table(x=c("A_1", "BB_2", "CC_3"),y=c("K_1", "LL_2", "MM_3"),z=c("P_1","QQ_2","RR_3"))            
dt[, nu_col := c(1:3)]
molten.dt<-melt(dt,id.vars = "nu_col", measure.vars = c("x","y","z"))
molten.dt[, one_more := ifelse(grepl("A_.*", value), "HONDA","FERRARI")]
```

The error that I see on Rstudio's console is :

```
Error in `:=`(one_more, ifelse(grepl("A_.*", value), "HONDA", "FERRARI")) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Runs perfectly fine on R Terminal

```
> dt<-data.table(x=c("A_1", "BB_2", "CC_3"),y=c("K_1", "LL_2", "MM_3"),z=c("P_$
> dt[, nu_col := c(1:3)]
> molten.dt<-melt(dt,id.vars = "nu_col", measure.vars = c("x","y","z"))
> molten.dt
   nu_col variable value
1:      1        x   A_1
2:      2        x  BB_2
3:      3        x  CC_3
4:      1        y   K_1
5:      2        y  LL_2
6:      3        y  MM_3
7:      1        z   P_1
8:      2        z  QQ_2
9:      3        z  RR_3
> molten.dt[, one_more := ifelse(grepl("A_.*", value), "HONDA","FERRARI")]
> molten.dt
   nu_col variable value one_more
1:      1        x   A_1    HONDA
2:      2        x  BB_2  FERRARI
3:      3        x  CC_3  FERRARI
4:      1        y   K_1  FERRARI
5:      2        y  LL_2  FERRARI
6:      3        y  MM_3  FERRARI
7:      1        z   P_1  FERRARI
8:      2        z  QQ_2  FERRARI
9:      3        z  RR_3  FERRARI
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has a different API for updating in place. While this would be [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```r
tib <- tib %>% mutate(new_col = old_col + 2)
```

The same thing is done in place using the `:=` operator:

```r
dt[, new_col := old_col + 2]
```

So note, once we are inside the brackets, we can pass a vector along to other functions. To apply that to your example, we can do...

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dt<-data.table(x=c("A_1", "BB_2", "CC_3"),y=c("K_1", "LL_2", "MM_3"),z=c("P_1","QQ_2","RR_3"))            

dt[, y := str_replace_all(y,c("K_.*" = "FORMULA","LL_.*" = "RACE","MM_.*" = "CAR")) ]               

dt

##         x       y      z
##    <char>  <char> <char>
## 1:    A_1 FORMULA    P_1
## 2:   BB_2    RACE   QQ_2
## 3:   CC_3     CAR   RR_3
```

Note, since `str_replace_all` expects a vector, you could have replaced `as.matrix(dt[,2])` with `dt[[2]]`. The difference is that `dt[, 2]` produces a single-column data.table; `as.matrix(dt[, 2])` produces a single column matrix, whereas `dt[[2]]` produces a vector. I would still recommend using `dt[, new := old + 2]` type of syntax.

Comment: Good Morning!. Thank you, I always prefer to have function used for data.table 's ```j``` argument. Your answer dispels confusion on both, single column usage vs. vector usage and the very popular ```:=``` usage. I stumbled on several other problems with character vectors and ```:=``` usage for ```j```.

Comment: Here is what I encountered while the foll.code was ran as RScript in RStuido's console: I edited my original post, apologies if this post is a little more noise

Comment: My only thought is that you have ```reshape2``` loaded. So instead of ```data.table::melt()``` you are actually calling ```reshape2::melt`()``. I was able to reproduce the error when I explicitly called ```reshape2::melt()```.  Note,  the edit was more of a new question.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was a new Q.  I thought to conclude the post with the suggested trial .. Not explicitly in the script, but yes ,in the RStudio environment, ```reshape``` was loaded. Won't that be "seen" in the R Terminal environment too?, to make it simple, In the environment I have both data.table and reshape2 loaded, and I assume that Rterminal and console have the same environment when accessed via Rstudio. I could be wrong.

Comment: Just one more on this.. I read through the ```melt()```documentation and I assume that at the R Terminal and in the Console, ```melt() ``` works the same way.

Comment: Sounds like a new question. If this answered your original, please accept.    I only use the console so I am not sure, but it sounds like it's a separate session. Type ```sessionInfo()``` to see what's loaded

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much